# How do I solve "Couldn't start client Rust Language Server" with the Rust VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

After installing the `Rust` extension for VS Code, building the project fails with the following error:

[image: Error Message Displayed by vscode]

> Couldn't start client Rust Language Server

> Rustup not available. Install from https://www.rustup.rs

This is in spite of the fact that `rustup` is installed in the system, and accessible from the VS Code terminal.

Comment: See also [Couldn't start client Rust Language Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58312319/155423)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is an oft-reported issue in the [rls-vscode](https://github.com/rust-lang/rls-vscode) repository, and I found the solution buried in some of the discussions ([1](https://github.com/rust-lang/rls-vscode/issues/622#issuecomment-561596264), [2](https://github.com/rust-lang/rls-vscode/issues/577#issuecomment-487231858)).

The issue seems to be with the path to the `rustup` executable.
`rustup` works fine on the terminal, but VS Code cannot locate it.

Adding the following to the `setting.json` of the extension fixes the path for the extension.

```
"rust-client.rustupPath": "/home/XXX/.cargo/bin/rustup"
```

Comment: If you are developing on remote SSH, make sure to edit your remote settings: Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) -> Open remote settings. Otherwise, the "rustupPath" setting will not be available.

Comment: `which rustup` gives me `/snap/bin/rustup`. I modified the setting in `settings.json` accordingly, reloaded, but the problem remains. Any suggestions?

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

@suj1th [first cited approach](https://github.com/rust-lang/vscode-rust/issues/622#issuecomment-561596264) fixed it for me.
Add: `"rust-client.rustupPath": "$HOME/.cargo/bin/rustup"` to your user settings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a debugging/troubleshooting guide: https://github.com/rust-lang/rls/blob/master/debugging.md

My fix was to launch VSCode from the terminal with `code`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

`Start > search for "Edit environment variables for account" > Edit "Path" > Add "%USERPROFILE%\.cargo\bin"`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using nightly.
Set it back to stable, then it worked:

```
cargo default stable
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the Windows path (without $HOME) to get it to work.

```
"rust-client.rustupPath": "C:/Users/myusername/.cargo/bin/rustup"
```